# How to call function on 'mixEnd' after filter has been applied in MixItUp jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, mixitup

**Desired Behaviour**

I am wanting to call a custom function after `mixItUp` has finished performing its filter function.

`MixItUp` is evoked on selecting a value from a dropdown.

**Current Behaviour**

To demonstrate and test functionality I am calling `alert()` on `mixEnd`.

The number of times the alert box shows after selecting a value is incrementing on each subsequent selection, ie after the first selection it shows once, after the second selection it shows twice.

**jQuery**

```
//define function
function initFilters() {
    $('#container').mixItUp({
        layout: {
            display: 'block'
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000,
            effects: 'translateZ(-360px) stagger(110ms) fade',
            easing: 'ease'
        }
    });
}

// call function
initFilters();

// define .on behavior
$('#area_filter, #rating_filter').on('change', function () {
    $('#container').mixItUp('filter', this.value);

    // do something on mixEnd
    $('#container').on('mixEnd', function(e, state){
        alert('MixItUp finished!');
    });

});
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/e3c6x29f/

**Steps To Reproduce**

- Visit jsFiddle.
- Select an area from the dropdown (one alert will show).
- Select another area from the dropdown (two alerts will show).

**Question**

There are a number of approaches to applying multiple functions and callbacks in `MixItUp` which are shown below.

My questions are therefore:

- How do I resolve the undesired behaviour of the alert box showing incrementally?
- Which of the following approaches is the most elegant way to achieve the desired behaviour (as I suspect my current approach is causing the problem)?

**Options**

**multiMix** (https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/docs/#method-multiMix)

Example:

```
$('#container').mixItUp('multiMix', {
    filter: '.category-1, .category-2',
    sort: 'name:asc',
    changeLayout: {
        containerClass: 'flex'
    }
});
```

**callback with onMixEnd** (https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/docs/#prop-callbacks-onMixEnd)

```
$('#container').mixItUp({
    callbacks: {
        onMixEnd: function(state){
            alert('Operation ended');
        }
    }
});
```

And there is also a example of this approach (which I am currently using):

```
$('#container').on('mixEnd', function(e, state){
    alert('MixItUp finished!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well here is one solution, still not sure if most elegant though, but it solves the undesired multiple triggering behaviour.

All I had to do was move the `.on('mixEnd', function(e, state)` out of the dropdown select area like so:

```
//define function
function initFilters() {
    $('#container').mixItUp({
    layout: {
        display: 'block'
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 1000,
        effects: 'translateZ(-360px) stagger(110ms) fade',
        easing: 'ease'
    }
    });
}

// do something on mixEnd <-- added here
$('#container').on('mixEnd', function(e, state){
alert('MixItUp finished!');
});

// call function
initFilters();

// define .on behavior
$('#area_filter, #rating_filter').on('change', function () {
    $('#container').mixItUp('filter', this.value);

// <-- removed from here

});
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/e3c6x29f/8/